# Overwrite records on SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create an SQLite query that gets all my data from my table on the last 24h, and I'm trying to overwrite the values depending on the day and the hour (eg. if the 18th at 00h we have the value 1 and at 19th at 00h we have the value 25 is supposed to show the 19th at 00h value and then the rest of 18th if there's not more records at 1am of 19th until 00h of the next day. I'm gonna leave a print of my output and the query I already have. The code can be in SQL and then I can do the changes to SQLite

**QUERY**

```
SELECT *
FROM teste
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', dt, '+9 hours') >= strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 'now', '-1 day', 'start of day');
```

**OUTPUT**

[OUTPUT OF THE QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOBMo.png)

I'll leave a print of the table too just so you can have a proper example of what I have right now.

[TABLE CONTENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHqxI.png)

I tried a lot of query's that ChatGPT tried to give me so I could have the desired output but no sucess, I expected to see the value of 00h of 19th on the top and then from 1am to 11pm of 18th showing under it  and instead either I got the values from 00h of 18th to 8am, or until 2pm or just returned nothing of the query

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: the only images I uploaded were the table in specific since I can't just upload a file to my question and to show the output of the query that I left the code of it on the question so I don't really understand your point on commenting this

Answer (score 0):

I found a query that solves my issue, I'll leave it here

```
WITH HourlyData AS (
  SELECT 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', dt) as hour_start,
    MAX(column_name) as max_value,
    MIN(column_name) as min_value
  FROM table_name
  WHERE dt >= datetime('now', '-24 hours')
  GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', dt)
)
SELECT 
  hour_start,
  max_value,
  min_value,
  max_value - min_value as diff_last_first
FROM HourlyData
ORDER BY hour_start ASC;
```